# The best solution to process the huge text file data in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, text-files, delphi-7

I have text file like this:

```
"01","AAA","AAAAA" 
"02","BBB","BBBBB","BBBBBBBB" 
"03","CCC" 
"04","DDD","DDDDD"
```

I want to load this text file data into temp table in sybase db. So, I need to build a program to read line by line this text file until eof. If the text file size is small, the process to read line by line is fast. But if text file size is too big (can be more than 500M), the process read line by line is too slow. I think the read line by line method not suitable for huge text file. So, need to find other solution to load text file data into db instead of read text file line by line method. Any suggestion?
Example code:

```
var
  myFile : TextFile;
  text   : string;

begin
  // Try to open the Test.txt file for writing to
  AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt');

  // Display the file contents
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, text);
    TempTable.append;
    TempTable.FieldByName('Field1').asstring=Copy(text,2,2);
    TempTable.FieldByName('Field2').asstring=Copy(text,7,3);
    TempTable.FieldByName('Field3').asstring=Copy(text,13,5);
    TempTable.FieldByName('Field4').asstring=Copy(text,21,8);
    TempTable.post;
  end;

  // Close the file for the last time
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

Comment: "Currently my Delphi program does this" means that you should have some code to post with your question. If you don't show us what you're doing now, how can we possibly suggest *another way* of doing it? Please [edit] your question to include information about what you're doing now and what "processing" means. We'd like to help, but it's necessary for you to actually describe the problem and show what you're doing if we're to provide an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you should include what database (DBMS) you're using, and what libraries/components you're using to work with it. Some database engines have command-line tools that would allow you to import data from text files into a database (or a temp DB) directly.

Comment: Thanks Ken White. I will edit my question as per your comment.

Comment: For very fast comma separated variable data transformation, and loading, use a database tool.  If your file is too large for memory, then you should be loading the data into an SQL database before any transformation, and do the transformation as the second stage.

Comment: Can Sybase's version of bcp handle this data? http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility195.htm

Comment: I already try to use sybase bcp. But, bcp not supported for the text file data with different number of separator(,).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general tips:

- Ensure your `TempTable` is in memory, or use a fast database engine - take a look at SQlite3 or other means (like FireBird embedded, NexusDB or ElevateDB) as possible database alternatives;
- If you do not use a `TTable`, but a true database, ensure you nest the insert *within a Transaction*;
- For a true database, check out if you can not use *ArrayDML* feature, which is much faster for inserting a lot of data as you want in a remote database (like Sybase) - [such Array DML is handled for instance with *FireDAC*](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/Array_DML.html) AFAIK;
- The `FieldByName('...')` method is known to be very slow: use locals `TField` variables instead;
- When using a TextFile, assign a bigger temporary buffer;
- If you are using newer Unicode versions of Delphi (2009+), using TextFile is not the best option.

So your code may be:

```
var
  myFile : TextFile;
  myFileBuffer: array[word] of byte;
  text   : string;
  Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4: TField;
begin

  // Set Field* local variables for speed within the main loop
  Field1 := TempTable.FieldByName('Field1');
  Field2 := TempTable.FieldByName('Field2');
  Field3 := TempTable.FieldByName('Field3');
  Field4 := TempTable.FieldByName('Field4');

  // Try to open the Test.txt file for writing to
  AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt');
  SetTextBuf(myFile, myFileBuffer); // use 64 KB read buffer

  // Display the file contents
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, text);
    TempTable.append;
    Field1.asInteger := StrToInt(Copy(text,2,2));
    Field2.asString := Copy(text,7,3);
    Field3.asString := Copy(text,13,5);
    Field4.asString := Copy(text,21,8);
    TempTable.post;
  end;

  // Close the file for the last time
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

You can achieve very high speed with embedded engines, with almost no size limit, but your storage. See for instance [how fast we can add content to a *SQLite3* database in our ORM](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/06/14/SQLite3-performance-in-Exclusive-file-locking-mode): about 130,000 / 150,000 rows per second in a database file, including all ORM marshalling. I also found out that *SQLite3* generates much smaller database files than alternatives. If you want fast retrieval of any field, do not forget to define *INDEXes* in your database, if possible *after* the insertion of row data (for better speed). For *SQLite3*, there is already an `ID/RowID` integer primary key available, which maps your first data field, I suppose. This `ID/RowID` integer primary key is already indexed by *SQLite3*. By the way, our ORM now supports [FireDAC / AnyDAC and its advanced Array DML feature](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/06/16/FireDAC-/-AnyDAC-support-for-mORMot).

Comment: For Unicode versions of Delphi, what is a better option than using TextFile?

Comment: Take a look at `TStreamReader`: you can use `TStreamReader.Create(aFileName[,encoding])` then use the `ReadLine` method. But be aware that the default `TEncoding` did change in newer versions: this is now `TEncoding.UTF8` - in your case, you may benefit of using `TEncoding.ASCII`.

Answer (score 5):

Text files normally have a very small buffer.  Look into using the [SetTextBuf function](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_SetTextBuf@Text@.html) to increase your performance.

```
var
  myFile : TextFile;
  text   : string;
  myFileBuffer: Array[1..32768] of byte;
begin
// Try to open the Test.txt file for writing to
  AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt');
  SetTextBuf(MyFile, myFileBuffer);
  Reset(MyFile);

// Display the file contents
  while not Eof(myFile) do
    begin
      ReadLn(myFile, text);
    end;

// Close the file for the last time
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

Comment: I'm new in programming and my english is not very well, so forgive me for that.

Comment: The old pascal file interface is deprecated. It is not thread safe, due to the use of a global variable to control open and sharing mode. Use TStream and its descendant.

Comment: @MadHatter `TStream` + `TTextReader` would add you flexibility, but not speed. So `ReadLn` is fine here.

Comment: No, ReadLn is no longer fine... it's time Delphi developers enter the XXI century and stop the TurboPascal mindset. Their still coding yesterday single threaded-applications as if they apps still run on DOS...

Comment: Hi, i have a question. Whats the effect if i increase the array of myFileBuffer to 64k?

Comment: @zed1308 I suspect almost unnoticeable in contrast to the default 128 bytes buffer, which is quite small. 32K is already good - but in most cases, it won't hurt to put 64KB or bigger. Just stay in values multiple the disk cluster size.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 7 you can use Turbo Power SysTools TStAnsiTextStream() to read and write in a line oriented way, but using the thread safe TStream implementation and not the unsafe old pascal file interface. In later Delphi versions you will find something alike in the standard RTL (although they are a little different in their implementation), but Delphi 7 didn't offer much for text file manipulation.

Comment: Keep on programming as if it was still 1983 guys, don't use threads in a multithread OS since 1995, and ensure your functions are not thread safe. Then ask yourself why Delphi became an obsolete tool to most. It's time to forget your Turbo Pascal "skills" and learn how to code XXI century applications. Instead of removing pointers and other low-end but powerful features, Embarcadero should start to remove old, unsafe Turbo Pascal features like Assign() and friends. But poor, old, obsolete "Delphi" developers would need to learn how to code...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, I would also avoid using any TTable component. You would be better off using a TQuery type component (depending on the access layer you're using). Something like this :-

```
qryImport.SQL := 'Insert Into MyTable Values (:Field1, :Field2, :Field3, :Field4);';

Procedure ImportRecord(Const pField1, pField2, pField3, pField4 : String);
Begin
  qryImport.Close;
  qryImport.Params[0].AsString := pField1;      
  qryImport.Params[1].AsString := pField2;`
  qryImport.Params[2].AsString := pField3;
  qryImport.Params[3].AsString := pField4;
  qryImport.ExecSQL;
End;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use memory-mapped files (you can google or go torry.net to find implementations). it would not work well for files >1gb (in win32,, in win64 you can map virtually any file). It would turn all your file into `PAnsiChar` that you would be able to scan like a one large buffer, searching for #10 and #13 (alone or in pairs) and thus manually splitting strings.

Comment: When reading a huge file once from the beginning to the end (which is the OP interest), memory mapped files will be slower than direct read operation with the file API, if the input buffer is big enough (bigger than 256 KB for instance). Memory mapping is only faster for random access, by design.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez 1GB file is laaarge for Win32 space but small for win64 address space. Would platform make a difference ?  Also - yes, it probably would not be faster than buffered read on win32 - but the parsing becomes easier on contiguous buffer. Of course exhaustion of address space and limitation to about 1,5 GB max size is a price to pay for that simplicity

Comment: I suspect Win64 won't be faster. What costs is the page misses and the low-level CPU exceptions which force the OS to change its internal state very often, whereas a plain API call will be more stable and won't interrupt the OS process flow. In mORMot, I use a lot memory mapped files, e.g. for log files viewing, but it is only convenient when I start browsing the file randomly, once I've read it through to compute the indexes and stats. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/20/Enhanced-Log-viewer

Answer (score 0):

If you use (or don't mind starting to use) the [JEDI Jvcl](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JEDI_Visual_Component_Library), they have a [`TJvCSVDataSet`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvCsvDataSet) which allows you to simply use your CSV file like any other dataset in Delphi, including being able to define persistent fields and use "standard" Delphi database functionality:

```
JvCSVDataSet1.FileName := 'MyFile.csv';
JvCSVDataSet1.Open;
while not JvCSVDataSet1.Eof do
begin
  TempTable.Append; // Posts last appended row automatically;
                    // no need to call Post here.

  // Assumes TempTable has same # of fields in the
  // same order
  for i := 0 to JvCSVDataSet1.FieldCount - 1 do
    TempTable.Fields[i].AsString := JvCSVDataSet1.Fields[i].AsString;
  JvCSVDataSet1.Next;  
end;

// Post the last row appended when the loop above exited
if TempTable.State in dsEditModes then
  TempTable.Post;
```